# uncheck checkbox which checked by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i check\uncheck checkboxes and radiobuttons, browser doesnt set attribute checked. So, when i am trying uncheck checkbox using jquery:

```
$('#tab2 input').removeAttr('checked');
```

it doesnt work. It works case checkbox was checked from my javascript code. How can i uncheck checkbox which already checked by user?

Comment: Since the API for this stuff changed recently, you should specify whether you're using jQuery 1.5.x or under, or jQuery 1.6 or above.

Comment: @Jamie Wong i'm using  jQuery 1.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting a property, so use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) in `jQuery 1.6`.

```
$('#tab2 input').prop('checked',false);
```

Or if there's only one `input`, just change the property of the element directly.

```
$('#tab2 input')[0].checked = false;
```

<s>When `jQuery 1.6.1` is released,</s> Or [upgrade to `jQuery 1.6.1`](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/) and you'll be able to go back to using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set properties again, but `.prop()` will still be the better way to do it.

From the release notes:

> Specifically, boolean attributes such as checked, selected, readonly, and disabled in 1.6.1 will be treated just as they used to be treated in jQuery versions prior to 1.6. This means that code such as
>
> ```
> $(“:checkbox”).attr(“checked”, true);
> $(“option”).attr(“selected”, true);
> $(“input”).attr(“readonly”, true);
> $(“input”).attr(“disabled”, true);
> ```
>
> or even:
>
> ```
> if ( $(“:checkbox”).attr(“checked”) ) { /* Do something */ }
> ```
>
> will not need to be changed in 1.6.1 in order to work as previously expected.

Comment: @Neir0: Using `.prop()` works for me in jQuery 1.6. There must be some other issue not visible in your question.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#tab2 input').attr('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', false);
```